# Do not wait for completion before continuing in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I am looking to launch a debugger program in the background from a Makefile.  I want the make call to complete and return and leave the debugger running.  It works fine from a shell but when I put it in the Makefile make waits around for all triggered processes to complete.

I have tried the following test target both with and without the `-`.

```
sleep:
    -sleep 5 &
```

Regardless, make sits around and waits for `sleep` to complete.

I do understand that this is not a normal usage of make but it would allow me to present the debugger launcher using the same sort of setup as the build targets.

Comment: Can't reproduce that. If I have a Makefile like yours with just 1 change: `sleep 5 && echo done &`, and I run `make`, it exits immediately to the commandline (after printing the command) and after 5 seconds I see "done".

Comment: This is a good example of me being a bad question asker.  From the command line it does as you say, from Eclipse it remains open.  So, my issue is not at all with make but rather eclipse.  I have voted to close my question since it is invalid.

Comment: Ah allright. Well, that makes sense - eclipse would keep the console open for the child processes spawned by make. Make probably has exited already (try adding a `echo after` after the sleep line as @Marcus suggests). You might try the `nohup`, aswell as redirecting stdin/stdout to /dev/null. And, you could always update your question!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an `echo "before"` before the `sleep` and an `echo "after"` after it?

What I think you'll notice is that Make does not wait for `sleep 5 &` itself to complete, but it waits for *all* processes started by a target to complete before considering that target to be complete. You will need to spawn a new process -- try `nohup <programname>` instead of `programname &`.

Comment: It does **not** wait for all processes started by a target to complete before considering that target to be complete, it exits immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question I should have asked would be:

```
sleep:
    cygstart sleep 5
```

Eclipse now considers the build finished immediately.